# How to detect if Windows 10 is in tablet mode with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10, tablet-pc

How would someone detect when a user enters tablet mode on a Windows 10 device with Delphi code?

Can someone show a code example for this?

I don't want to detect if the user has a tablet or not. I simply want to see whether they're in tablet mode or not. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate (not Delphi but same question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153664/how-can-i-detect-when-windows-10-enters-tablet-mode-in-a-windows-forms-applicati#32417768

Comment: @Remko I've seen that question, but mine is specific to Delphi.

Comment: The answer applies to Delphi, sometimes you have to go native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the previous variant (based on [[SO]: How can I detect when Windows 10 enters tablet mode in a Windows Forms application? (@CheeseLover's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32417768/4788546) (pointed out by @Remko's comment)) because it's a totally different scenario (doesn't have anything to do with *Win* running on desktop).

I spent some time on [[MS.DevBlogs]: Raymond - How can I detect whether my PC is in tablet mode?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=93815) (pointed out in @RitaHan-MSFT's answer (+1)), and clearly, **that's the way to go**.

I don't know how to "translate" the code into *Delphi*, as many years passed since I wrote significant amounts of code in it (but I'm sure it's possible), so I did the next best thing: wrote a *C++* *.dll* (containing a modified / improved version of Raymond's code) that is called from *Delphi*.

**Note**: *VStudio* is required to build the *.dll*, I used *2015 **Community** Edition*, which is free and can be downloaded from [[VStudio]: Visual Studio 2015 and other Products](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads) (you need an *MS* account though).

*dll.cpp*:

```cpp
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include <windows.ui.viewmanagement.h>
#include <UIViewSettingsInterop.h>
#include <wrl/wrappers/corewrappers.h>


namespace WRL = Microsoft::WRL;
namespace VM = ABI::Windows::UI::ViewManagement;


class Backend {
public:
    static Backend &instance()
    {
        static Backend m_instance;
        return m_instance;
    }

    WRL::ComPtr<IUIViewSettingsInterop> interop() {return m_interop;}

private:
    Backend()
    {
        HRESULT res = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
        m_comInit = (res == S_OK) || (res == S_FALSE);
        if (m_comInit || (res == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)) {
            res = Windows::Foundation::GetActivationFactory(WRL::Wrappers::HStringReference(
                RuntimeClass_Windows_UI_ViewManagement_UIViewSettings).Get(), &m_interop);
        }
    }

    Backend(const Backend &other) = delete;
    Backend &operator =(const Backend &other) = delete;

    ~Backend()
    {
        if (m_interop) {m_interop.Reset();}
        if (m_comInit) {CoUninitialize();}
    }

    bool m_comInit = false;
    WRL::ComPtr<IUIViewSettingsInterop> m_interop = nullptr;
};


/*!
    Gets Tablet mode value.
    \param hwnd Window handle to get the mode for
    \returns:
         1 - Tablet mode ON
         0 - Tablet mode OFF
        -X - Error
*/
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int GetTabletMode(HWND hwnd)
{
    WRL::ComPtr<IUIViewSettingsInterop> interop = Backend::instance().interop();
    if (!interop) {
        return -3;
    }

    WRL::ComPtr<VM::IUIViewSettings> viewSettings;
    HRESULT res = interop->GetForWindow(hwnd != NULL ? hwnd : GetConsoleWindow(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&viewSettings));
    if (!viewSettings) {
        return -2;
    }

    VM::UserInteractionMode currentMode;
    res = viewSettings->get_UserInteractionMode(&currentMode);

    int ret = -1;
    switch (currentMode) {
        case VM::UserInteractionMode_Mouse: ret = 0; break;
        case VM::UserInteractionMode_Touch: ret = 1; break;
        default: ret = -1;
    }

    viewSettings.Reset();
    return ret;
}
```

Below is the *Delphi* relevant code (only the unit, as the rest can easily be manufactured, and there's no point placing it all here).

*Unit0.pas*:

```pascal
unit Unit0;

interface

uses
    Forms, Dialogs, Controls, StdCtrls, Classes;


type
    TForm0 = class(TForm)
    CheckButton: TButton;
        procedure CheckButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        { Private declarations }
    public
        { Public declarations }
end;

var
    Form0: TForm0;


    function GetTabletMode(hwnd: THandle): Integer cdecl; external 'TabletUtils.dll';


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm0.CheckButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
    TabletModeStr: String;
begin
    case GetTabletMode(Self.Handle) of
        0 : TabletModeStr := 'OFF';
        1 : TabletModeStr := 'ON';
        else TabletModeStr := 'ERROR';
    end;
    MessageDlg('Tablet Mode: ' + TabletModeStr, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end;

end.
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q056321591]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> "c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x86
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> App0.cfg
> App0.dof
> App0.dpr
> App0.exe
> App0.res
> dll.cpp
> other
> Unit0.dcu
> Unit0.ddp
> Unit0.dfm
> Unit0.pas
>
> [prompt]> cl /nologo /DDLL /DNDEBUG /DUSRDLL /D_WINDOWS /MT dll.cpp  /link /NOLOGO /DLL /OUT:TabletUtils.dll ole32.lib runtimeobject.lib
> dll.cpp
>    Creating library TabletUtils.lib and object TabletUtils.exp
>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> App0.cfg
> App0.dof
> App0.dpr
> App0.exe
> App0.res
> dll.cpp
> dll.obj
> other
> TabletUtils.dll
> TabletUtils.exp
> TabletUtils.lib
> Unit0.dcu
> Unit0.ddp
> Unit0.dfm
> Unit0.pas
>
> [prompt]> App0.exe
>
> [prompt]>
> ```

In the screenshot below, I ran the application:

- On my laptop (*Win 10*) with *Desktop mode* (right side)
- On a *Win 10* *VM* with *Tablet mode* (left side). Note that I had to copy:

  - *App0.exe*
  - *TabletUtils.dll*

[image: Img0]

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIViewSettings.UserInteractionMode API. Please refer to [@Raymond blog: "How can I detect whether my PC is in tablet mode?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=93815), there are UWP and desktop ways in C++ you can refer to.

More detailed information you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225753/how-to-detect-if-windows-10-is-in-tablet-mode).

But you need find out how to do in Delphi. There are some related issues hope they are helpful for you:

[delphi - call external WinAPI function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378993/delphi-call-external-winapi-function)

[Can we call Native Windows API from Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920950/can-we-call-native-windows-api-from-delphi)